# How to handle Python executable path on mac?

Tags: python, macos, file

How to make a program (*executable*) to check some `.csv files`. The program should work on a file located in the same directory and he uses a ***MAC***. The problem is:

When I create a mac executable from my code, an *.app* is created. As this is sort of an archive the working directory changes. What is the correct way to access the files in the same folder as the *.app*?

I hacked a solution by looking how a .app is constructed. Then I read the directory path and removed a few characters from this string. It works, but is not pretty. If you have ideas, how to make it nicer, it would be appreciated. Here is what I did:

```
dirhack=os.getcwd()
csvpath=dirhack[0:(len(dirhack)-32)]+'/'
...
with open(csvpath+filename,'wb') as csv_file:
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`os.getcwd()` does not return the directory of the file. For this, you would need `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` Where `__file__` is a python constant to indicate the current python file.

However, if the point is simply to make the file executable, you don't need to make an app of it. Open a terminal, go to the file and do `chmod a+x file.py`. This will make it executable from the terminal (meaning you can run it with `./file.py`.)

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately the terminal way is out, as my friend doesn't have python nor does he even use terminal.

Comment: if your friend doesn't have python, how is he planning to get this script running?

Comment: This is exactly why I had to make an executable .app - a script wouldn't do. In the case of a script, this whole problem would not emerge. For this I used PyInstaller. Of course, the result is not universal but made do in this case.

Comment: Then I would still go for the `os.path.dirname` solution. I'm guessing your Python source code will be in the `.app` directory. If that's true, `appdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` will point to the `.app` directory itself and `topdir=os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))` should point to the directory where the `.app` directory is in. With that, you can find the csv files in that directory with `os.path.join(topdir, filename)` (assuming you know the file name. Otherwise you might have to search for the file using `glob`)